# c# How do I unsubscribe a private method subscribed to an event from it's derived class?

Tags: c#, delegates, eventhandler

How do we unsubscribe a private method subscribed to an event from it's derived class?

For eg:

Base Class :

```
class Base1 
{
    public Command Comm;
    public Base1(){

    Comm.OnFailed += DoSomething;
    }

    private void DoSomething(Exception ex){
    //do something
    }
}
```

Derived Class :

```
class Derived1 : Base1{

    public Derived1(){
    // Here I need to unsubscribe DoSomething before subscribing to DoSomethingElse
    Comm.OnFailed += DoSomethingElse;
    }
    private void DoSomethingElse(Exception ex){
    //do something else
    }
}
class Command
{
event Action<Exception> OnFailed;
}
```

Here, at derived class, I need to unsubscribe "DoSomething" and subscribe "DoSomethingElse" to OnFailed.

- I cannot change the base class.
- I tried to assign null (`Comm.OnFailed = null;`) but didn't work and thow CS0079 error. The event 'Command.OnFailed' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

Comment: The code in your question doesn't compile. `DoSomething` and `DoSomethingElse` should take an `Exception` parameter, and the line `Comm.OnFailed += DoSomethingElse;` should be inside a method/constructor. `OnFailed` should also be public.  right?

Comment: Though this is possible with reflection, you should reconsider why the derived class should know about the private methods of its base class at all. The private method is part of the base class's implementation details, and you shouldn't be relying on it anyway. Your code could easily break in the future if `base1` changes in some way. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Maybe you could assign a new instance to  Comm in the derived ctor and register the eventhandling...? So you don't need to unregister the original, since it never fires...

Comment: @Sweeper : OnFailed is public. I want to remove the base implementation of OnFailed and override with my logic. I would prefer to remove all subscriptions to OnFailed and all my logic in derived class (DoSomethingElse). .

Comment: @dba: in this case, both DoSomething & DoSomethingElse will be excuted. Here I dont want 'DoSomething' to be executed.

Comment: I don't think so... Creating a new instance on derived first calls the ctor of base then executes the block of derived. So if you assign a new value to Comm after the base ctor, it's gone

Comment: You seem to misunderstand events. There is no interface to "remove all subscription". For an event, its public interface only includes "add an event handler" and "remove an event handler" (think of an event as just a pair of methods). You can't remove all event handlers unless you know which ones are added.

Comment: As an aside, it would be really helpful if you could follow normal C# naming conventions in your sample code - types should start with a capital letter; parameters shouldn't. I'd also apply conventional formatting. Anything unconventional distracts from the question itself.

Comment: If you follow [Publish events based on the EventHandler pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-publish-events-that-conform-to-net-framework-guidelines#publish-events-based-on-the-eventhandler-pattern) you get automatically a solution. There is no need for a class to subscribe to an own event.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Derived1 : Base1{

public Derived1(){
Comm.OnFailed=delegate(Exception ex){}
Comm.OnFailed += DoSomethingElse;
}
private void DoSomethingElse(Exception ex){
//do something else
}
class Command
{
    public delegate void Failed(Exception ex);

    public Failed OnFailed;
}
```

because **Derived1 class** can't access Dosomething in  **Base1 class*  and he can't modify **Base1 class** so it is better to change OnFailed form event to delegate(which support -,+,=) and this way will enable him to reset OnFailed
I hope this code answers your question

Comment: Can you edit your answer to explain _how_ it answers their question?